# Look up titles in sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two Google sheets - the first list of courses with an ID

Sheet name - Unique Id_Class

| CourseID | Course Name |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Business. |
| 234 | IT |
| 456 | Management |

I have a second table is a list of students

Sheet Name is New API Call

| StudentID | CourseID | Course Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 654321 | 123 |  |
| 654321 | 234 |  |
| 789876 | 123 |  |
| 789876 | 456 |  |

I am trying to populate the Course Name in the second table from the first table. As more rows are added to the second table I want to automatically populate the Course Name column.

I have tried a vlookup but can't get that to work. I am now trying to create a script that uses a Query that will be added to each row as new rows are added but I am getting a continual error of a missing bracket but I can't figure out why.

```
    function CourseTitle(){

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("New API Call");

    var cell = sheet.getRange("C2:C");
    cell.setFormula("=QUERY('Unique Id_Class'!A:B,"SELECT A, B WHERE ((A = "&C2&"))", 
    true)");
     };
```

Any advice on what I am doing wrong will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you solved your issue also consider adding your own answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write a script that copies formula. ARRAYFORMULA will do it for you.

```
=ArrayFormula(ifna(vlookup(G3:G,B3:C,2,false)))
```

[image]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S3uAt4Tmz2c9-efTLs2zsgykdzvbIzknA57hFxc7eL8/copy

Comment: Thanks Krzysztof, figured out the other issue so added (ifna(vlookup(TEXT(H2:H,"#") to your formula and it now works perfectly.